# C# ASP How to store data between the same page and multiple clients?

Tags: c#, webforms, static

I am writing a scoreboard application for tracking the progress of a manufacturing line and provide real time feedback to the operators. In order to reduce on database calls, I load a bunch of data when the user clicks on the menu item in the scoreboard and store it in a public static class.

The system I found that seems to work best is the to kick off background threads for each long running query (15-30 seconds) every 2 minutes.

```
                    //kick off update every 2 minutes
                if (Info.counter == 24)
                {
                    Thread t = new Thread(LoadScoreboard); t.Start();
                    Thread t2 = new Thread(LoadGridview); t2.Start();
                    Info.counter = 0;
                }
```

Then when the data finishes pulling I load it into a public static dataset.

```
public static DataSet gridviewDS = new DataSet();
public static List<string> iList = new List<string>();
```

My update panel fires every 5 seconds on a timer tick event and updates the front end with whatever is in the static variables.

```
                    //populate gridview
                if (gridviewDS.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    gvDataDisplay.DataSource = gridviewDS;
                    gvDataDisplay.DataBind();
                }
```

*This all works great, if only 1 client is running.* As soon as I open a second browser at a different manufacturing line, my variables are shared between the lines and my data is summed.

**My question is, how do I store data the entire time the app is open, but it be separate for each client?**

I was reading about Session state variables, but that seems to be a solution for storing data between multiple pages in the same app. I need to store data between the same page and multiple clients. I have only been a full stack developer for less than 12 months, so forgive me if I made an obvious error somewhere.

Comment: So ASP.Net? - Are you looking for the [Application Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.100).aspx) ?

Comment: Session state variables is still the way to go. Maybe "storing data between multiple requests in the same app during one session" is a better explanation.

Comment: @AlexK. The application cache is shared for all clients.

Comment: @ Alex K, yes ASP.net webforms app, using VS2015. I will have to read up on the Application Cache this afternoon, that may be a great solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Paul, Ok if I use Session state variables I was having problems in VS2015. I have added System.Web in my references and I added the using statement, but when I try to use HttpContext.Items.Current intellisense doesn't recognize it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Within a webform which inherits `System.Web.UI.Page` you should be able to access it with `Session["someKey"]`. If you don't have direct access `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items` should do work. You switched `Current` and `Items`in your comment. Did the same happen within your code? Edit: The session data is stored in `Session` and not `Items`. Data in `Items` does not persist between multiple requests.

Comment: Yup, that's what I did wrong. I had Current and Items switched. Thanks, I will try these two suggestions.